# Can't use my custom module when I try to run a Flask app with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to run a Flask app with gunicorn. I can run it by using python3 command but when it comes to run it with `gunicorn app:app` it cannot recognize my custom module and gives the error in the below section:

`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FeatureEliminator' on <module '__main__' from '/home/smartmodel/anaconda3/bin/gunicorn'>`

I have already imported this module in my app.py file

```
from feature_eliminator import FeatureEliminator
```

I also created an **init**.py

[image]

I expected to run my Flask app with gunicorn

**feature_eliminator.py**

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class FeatureEliminator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, CORR_THRESHOLD=0.9, feature_column_names = None):
        self.CORR_THRESHOLD = CORR_THRESHOLD
        self.eliminated_features_ = None
        self.feature_column_names = feature_column_names

    def fit(self, X):
        feature_corrs = np.abs(np.corrcoef(X, rowvar=False))
        eliminated_features = []
        for i in range(feature_corrs.shape[0]):
            for k in range(feature_corrs.shape[1]):
                if i != k and i not in eliminated_features and feature_corrs[i, k] > self.CORR_THRESHOLD:
                    eliminated_features.append(i)
    
        if eliminated_features:
            print(f'Correlated Features: {self.feature_column_names[eliminated_features]}')
            feature_vars = np.var(X[:, eliminated_features], axis=0)
            max_var_index = np.argmax(feature_vars)
            eliminated_features.pop(max_var_index)
            print(f'Eliminated Features: {self.feature_column_names[eliminated_features]}')
    
        self.eliminated_features_ = eliminated_features
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        if self.eliminated_features_ is None:
            raise ValueError("Fit the model first before transforming the data.")
        reduced_X = np.delete(X, self.eliminated_features_, axis=1)
        return reduced_X

    # Function to combine fit and transform steps
    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        self.fit(X)
        return self.transform(X)
```

Comment: Can you show the content of feature_eliminator.py?